# Как из фотогалереи iOS получить все фото, кроме добавленных в избранное?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Получаю все фото и видео из галереи мобильного устройства с помощью кода:

```
struct PHAssetMediaContainer {
    let images: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>
    let videos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>
    var count: Int {
        return images.count + videos.count
    }
}
 
 
 
func getAllMedia() -> PHAssetMediaContainer {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
       
        return PHAssetMediaContainer(images:PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions),
                                     videos: PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions))
    }
```

Как получить массив фото и видео, которые добавлены/не добавлены в избранное?

Или получить также все, но с дополнительным параметром — "добавлен в избранное - да/нет".

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать свойство `PHAsset` `isFavorite`

```
    func getAllMedia() -> PHAssetMediaContainer {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

        let container = PHAssetMediaContainer(images:PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions), videos: PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions))
        
        container.images.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, stop) in
            print(index, asset.isFavorite)
        }
        
        return container
    }
```